# Help using Dynamic PL/SQL, function throwing exception

Tags: sql, exception, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am rather new at PL/SQL (esp. using Dynamic SQL), I created this function, and it runs/compiles without any errors or warnings, but when I run the function....

```
SELECT schema.fa_awd_for_term('0000000','2003SPRING',NULL,NULL)
FROM DUAL;
```

....It throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the EXCEPTION handlers and you will find out what the error actually is.  You should not explicitly handle unexpected exceptions.

It would also be better to use bind variables e.g. change this:

```
    || 'substr(ta_xxxx_id,1,7) = ''sssssss'' '
    || 'and substr(ta_xxxx_id,instr(ta_xxxx_id,''*'',1,2)+1) = ''aaaa'' '
```

to

```
    || 'substr(ta_xxxx_id,1,7) = :sssssss '
    || 'and substr(ta_xxxx_id,instr(ta_xxxx_id,''*'',1,2)+1) = :aaaa '
```

then add a USING clause to the OPEN statement:

```
OPEN CUR_faawards FOR thequery USING id, v_year;
```

and remove the REPLACE code for these.  I'm afraid you are stuck with 'xxxx' due to the awful table design - a column for each year?!?!

Comment: yes, I know :( it is poorly designed.  I will try these suggestions, and get back to you.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: okay, I tried moving the bottom exception (where it returns 'ER2'), and I get an ora-06512, unhandled exception, and the error above it is "table or view does not exist (I have double checked my table names for accuracy) does this give any hint to the problem?

Comment: It could be any of the tables, but my suspicions would begin with the ta_xxxx tables.  Try adding some debug messages e.g. using dbms_output.put_line.

Comment: okay, dumb, rookie question. Can i use dbms_output.put_line(); to print out a variable? So for instance can I do dbms_output.put_line(v_year); and have it output when the function is run?

Comment: Yes but only when running the function within a development environment like SQL Plus, SQL Developer or Toad.  If you call the function from an application there is no easy access to the output of that.  A common alternative is to write debug messages to a table using an autonomous transaction - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568166/log-error-messages-in-oracle-stored-procedure